# How to be right created a self proxy server for ipfs files?

Tags: ether, javascript, nft, ipfs, user-experience

I'am fetching many data from ipfs for different users. I want to distribute these files through my own server. How will it be done correctly, create a simple proxy server or download images while saving them id?